# 2d platformer arrow follows me?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, 2d-games

I am creating a web application canvas game with javascript.
At the moment I am trying to have one of the enemies shoot an arrow at my character. I want to eventually do parabolic projection, but for now I want just a simple line between two points.

Right now i have kinda accomplished this, but when my character moves back and forth the arrows being shot follow him. I know that this is because when my character moves, the canvasX and Y for the enemy gets adjusted, and thus it updates the arrow, what I don't know is how to fix it.

```js
function SkeletonArcher(game, x, y) {

  this.ctx = game.ctx;
  this.name = "skeletonArcher";

  this.animationAttackLeft = new Animation(this, attackLeftAnimationSpriteSheet, 288, 192, 4, 0.05, 16, true, 0.5);

  var currentCharacter = game.getCurrentCharacter();

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.width = 2 * 16;
  this.height = 4 * 16;

  this.canvasX = x;
  this.canvasY = y;

  this.attacking = false;
}
SkeletonArcher.prototype.update = function() {
  var gameEngine = this.game;
  var currentCharacter = gameEngine.getCurrentCharacter();
  if (this.animationAttackLeft.currentFrame() === 11) {
    var startTime = this.game.timer.gameTime;
    var newArrow = new Arrow(this.game, this.canvasX, this.canvasY, startTime);
    this.game.addEntity(newArrow);
  }
  // here is where the enemy gets adjusted on the canvas
  if (gameEngine.keyMap["KeyD"] && !currentCharacter.collidedRight) {

    this.canvasX -= 3;

  } else if (gameEngine.keyMap["KeyA"] && !currentCharacter.collidedLeft) {

    this.canvasX += 3;
  }

  if (currentCharacter.canvasX >= this.canvasX - 800 && !this.attacking) {
    this.animationState = "attackLeft";
    this.attacking = true;
  }
  if (currentCharacter.canvasX <= this.canvasX - 800) {
    this.attacking = false;
    this.animationState = "idleLeft";
  }
};

function Arrow(game, archerX, archerY, startTime) {
  this.startTime = startTime;
  this.game = game;
  this.ctx = game.ctx;
  this.name = "arrow";
  var currentCharacter = game.getCurrentCharacter();

  this.x = archerX;
  this.y = archerY;

  this.width = 2 * 16;
  this.height = 4 * 16;
  this.canvasX = archerX;
  this.canvasY = archerY;
  this.y1 = this.canvasY;
  this.y2 = currentCharacter.canvasY;
  this.x1 = this.canvasX;
  this.x2 = currentCharacter.canvasX;

}

Arrow.prototype.update = function() {
  var currentCharacter = this.game.getCurrentCharacter();
  var gameEngine = this.game;

  var timeSince = this.game.timer.gameTime - this.startTime;
  this.canvasY = (1 - timeSince) * this.y1 + (timeSince * this.y2);
  this.canvasX = (1 - timeSince) * this.x1 + (timeSince * this.x2);

};


Arrow.prototype.draw = function(first_argument) {
  this.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  this.ctx.fillRect(this.canvasX, this.canvasY, 5, 3);

};
```

Comment: han! you made homing missiles before arrows ... For your problem I didn't read the code at all, but can't you just save the aimed coordinates when the arrow is launched in a new variable, or even just the axis vector, instead of using the player's coordinates every time ?

Comment: @Kaiido could you give me an example?

Comment: when i do this it still follows me

Comment: In your Arrow constructor, add `targetX` and Y properties. Set it only at init to the personna's coords , then in the update use these instead of the character's one.